# Is it necessary to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK in a Notification's PendingIntent?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I have been using `Notification`s for a while, and yesterday I noticed that the documentation of `PendingIntent` says that the Intent that is passed to the [`PendingIntent.getActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29)method must have the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` set:

> Note that the activity will be started outside of the context of an
>   existing activity, so you must use the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
>   launch flag in the Intent.

However, I have never set this flag when using `Notification`s, and yet so far I have not experienced any problem. I have seen out there several examples of `Notification`s where the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is not set for the `Intent` that the `PendingIntent` is referencing. In particular, the [official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Basics) shows the snippet below:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";
CharSequence contentText = "Hello World!";
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
```

And as you can see, they are not setting the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag. So my question is, should I always set the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag when using `PendingIntent.getActivity()`, or are there some scenarios in which it can be omitted? In particular, when using `Notification`s, can I use an Intent without setting this flag?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the system sets it for you for notifications.  You will get a new task when launched from a notification.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. Otherwise you may get unexpected behavior on some devices.

As of today (March 25, 2017) the [official guide linked in the question](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) has this updated code snippet:

```
// Creates an Intent for the Activity
Intent notifyIntent =
        new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
// Sets the Activity to start in a new, empty task
notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
// Creates the PendingIntent
PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        0,
        notifyIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);
```

Comment: The code snippet is now here: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation Further, it should be noted that using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` is definitely _not_ required; the code snippet is for a "special activity" that is started in a separate task.